# How to get around child element in a UL issue

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to Validate to HTML5 standards and have 1 error left which I can't get passed.

"Element section not allowed as child of element ul in this context." is the error, which I've found covered below and I know is a no-no. It works perfectly, it just doesn't validate.

[Allowed child elements of ul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242041/allowed-child-elements-of-ul)

My question is how to I get around it? I'm trying to get a .js button to work within a Nav bar. I've tried every way I can think of to nest it and no luck. Either I lose the .css and it looks like a standard button and/or lose my positioning.

Here's the code. Thanks a lot!

```
<ul class="navlinks">
   <section>
    <li><a href="...">link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="...">link2</a></li>
    <li><button id="contactpanel">Contact</button></li>
  </section></ul>

.navlinks {

    border-left:orange solid 1px; 
margin-left:6%;
margin-top:10%;
    z-index: 6;
position:fixed;
font-size:1.1em;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
color:#18112D;
list-style:none;
font-weight:500;
padding-left:6px;
padding-top:20px;
padding-bottom:20px;
}

.navlinks > section {
outline: none;
}

.navlinks > section button {
border: none;
display: block;
width:100%;
cursor: pointer;
z-index:6;
font-size:1em;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
color:#18112D;
font-weight:500;
margin-left:-7px;
    outline: none;
background-color:transparent;
}

.navlinks > section button:hover {
color:#514966; 
opacity:0.3;
color:#18112D;
height:auto;
}

.navlinks > section button.active {
background-color: orange;
opacity:1;
color:white;
    outline: none;
    padding-right:18px;
}
```

Comment: [It looks fine to me if you just completely get rid of the `<section>`.](http://jsfiddle.net/a7pBA/) It's not at all clear what led you to conclude that a `<section>` like that was a solution to some problem.

Comment: Surely the section is the whole list, not the list items? In that case, put the section around the ul, not within it, and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting rid of the `<section>` and targeting the button with this selector `.navlinks li > button`. See example [codepen](http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/e46ddcc2fbe789d0620c518d8408b1fd).

Comment: Wooooo! You guy's are great, that was it. Thanks a million! Stress level subsiding.

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the `<section>` tags all together (or wrap the whole `<ul>` in it). It's not doing anything for you here anyway.

Then change `.navlinks > section button` to `.navlinks button`

Comment: No, it should be `.navlinks button` - there's an `<li>` between the `<ul>` and the `<button>` tag.

Comment: Ahh, yes. Thanks, Pointy. Editing answer to include this.

Comment: Was actually this answer that did it. (sorry) Thanks again!