# Issue with nested ul + li elements

Tags: html, html-lists

I have pasted some code below, which seems to be causing an issue. As far as I can see everything is poisitioned and opened/closed in the right places, but dreamweaver is highlighting some as a warning. The highlights are occuring on the following item and it's corresponding closing tag:

```
<li class="menu-item"><a href="">Work</a>
```

The code:

```
                <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">About</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Work</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <div class="grid">
                                <div class="unit one-fifth sub-menu-item">
                                    <h3>Filter</h3>
                                    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*">Everything</a></li>
                                    <?php 
                                    $terms = get_terms("category"); // get all categories, but you can use any taxonomy
                                    $count = count($terms); //How many are they?
                                    if ( $count > 0 ){  //If there are more than 0 terms
                                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {  //for each term:
                                    echo "<li><a href='#' data-filter='.".$term->slug."'>" . $term->name . "</a></li>\n";
                                    //create a list item with the current term slug for sorting, and name for label
                                    }
                                    } 
                                    ?>
                    </li>
                                </div>

                                <div class="unit one-fifth sub-menu-item">
                                    <h3>Recent</h3>
                                </div>

                                <div class="unit two-fifths sub-menu-item">
                                    <h3>Archive</h3>
                                </div>

                                <div class="unit one-fifth sub-menu-item">
                                    <h3>Featured Project</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="">News</a>
                </ul>

            <button class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Primary Menu', 'citizen-films' ); ?></button>
            </nav>
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

An ul tag can only contain li as children.
So this, isn't valid.

```
 <ul class="dropdown">
                        <div class="grid">
```

You can however place the div in an li tag.

Take a look at this question:
[Allowed child elements of ul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242041/allowed-child-elements-of-ul)