# Aside element spills over/under

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

Having an issue styling the aside element on my page. When I use `height: 100%;` it spills into the div immediately following it. 
[See example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeD52.png)

But when I use

```
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

It goes under the navbar. [See example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl1m9.png)

Can anyone explain why? Im more of a Rails guy than CSS.

HTML:

```
<div class="properties-results">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="pr-row">

  <div id='map'></div>
<aside>
<h1>Recent Sales Near <%= params[:search] %></h1>
<ul>
  <% @comps.each do |comparable|%>
  <li><%= comparable.street %></li>
  <i> <%= comparable.sold_price%></i>
  <% end %>
</ul>
</aside>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="individual-properties">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <% @comps.each do |comparables| %>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="list-group">
          <h3 class="list-group-text"><%= comparables.street %></h3>
          <p class="list-group-text"><%= comparables.square_feet %> square feet</p>
          <p class="list-group-text">List Price: <%= comparables.list_price %></p>
          <p class="list-group-text">Sold Price: <%= comparables.sold_price %></p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.properties-results {
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 401px;

}

#pr-row {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

aside{
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 195px;
    background-color: #000;
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
        }
}

  #map {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 260px;

    }

#individual-properties {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.list-group {
    border-top: 1px solid #006699;

}

.list-group-text {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your code in a jsfiddle where we can see it working like in your images? I tried and it does not behave the same, so any solution wouldn't be reliable.

Comment: _It goes under the navbar_ You forgot to include the navbar markup and styles

Comment: JS fiddle added here :https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=0K88rSBiDh

Comment: I used bootstrap classes for the nav - `navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add `position:relative;` to your `.properties-results` style to anchor the `aside` off of

Also make sure that your `<ul>` only has `<li>`'s as children, see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242041/allowed-child-elements-of-ul)

Comment: That seemed to do it. Thanks for your help.