# Creating <select> forms on new lines with javascript DOM document.createElement

Tags: javascript, html, createelement

i need to create  forms on new lines when i hit a button, using javascript and document.createElement.
When i do it, it keeps creating new forms on the same line.

To better explain the problem i'll give you a link to jsfiddle.net

```
function myFunction() {
   var select = document.createElement("select");
   document.getElementById("list").appendChild(select);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cnenms77/2/

Comment: do you want to add select tag inside li tags? like this https://jsfiddle.net/cnenms77/8/

Comment: i need to send <select> forms on new lines instead of the same line

Comment: if you put select inside li then select tags visible in new lines . it's default li behavior

Comment: the best solution is the one from @Omarjmh, so i can give to select the style.

Comment: the answer do.but there is standards .see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol . Permitted content in a ul tags : `Zero or more <li> elements` .

Comment: the above is correct, I will edit my answer to reflect the correct standard as to not mislead, @FastSnail does indeed have the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are derectly adding select tags without li tags .it's **invalid**.
correct way is to use li tags .

read standards for UL tag [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol).

read this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242041/allowed-child-elements-of-ul) too.

by default li tags starting from new line.
so the structure should be

```
<ul id="list">
     <li><select></select></li>
     <li><select></select></li>
     <li><select></select></li>
</ul>
```

in javascript you create `li` element and then append `select` tag to it .then you can add elements `ul` list. [preview](https://jsfiddle.net/cnenms77/8/)

```
function myFunction() {
    var select = document.createElement("select");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(select);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: this is the correct answer