# Text After a Z-Index Image?

Tags: html, css, z-index, banner

I'm making a website and I have a banner which is just an image with a Z-Index of -1. It has 2 lines of text over the top of it as well as the transparent navigation bar at the top. Is there a way to write a paragraph underneath the banner without it overlaying onto the image?

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppdermx5)**

```
<ul class="Nav">
    <div class="Logo">
        <img src="Logo.png">
    </div>
    <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="Banner">
<div class="Banner">
    <img class="Banner-Image" src="Img/Banner1.jpg">
<div class="Title">
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<h1>BradTech</h1>
<p>Professional Website Development and  Graphic Design</p>
</div></div>
</ul>
<ul class="Text">
<p>I want this paragraph underneath.</p>
```

```
Body {
    font-family: 'Arial', Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.nav {
    color: #000000;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 25px 0 25px;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.nav > li > a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #000000;
}

.nav > li > a:hover {
color: #666666;
}

.Logo {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 25px
}

.Banner {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.Banner > .Banner-Image {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
}

.Title  {
    text-align: center;
}

.Title > h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
}

.Text {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

[What the website looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94Gny.jpg)

Comment: Could you post the example in JSFiddle or paste some sample code? If the image is block level, a subsequent paragraph should automatically display underneath.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ppdermx5/

Comment: Other child elements in a `ul` other than `li` is invalid HTML, though it is possible to style, you should never use anything else, in any case. Also see this post: [Allowed child elements of ul](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242041/allowed-child-elements-of-ul)

Answer (score 0):

If you use absolute positioning, the last addition will be shown on top.

for example to place top left:

```
style='position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;'
```

html example:

```
<p style='position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;'>
 foo 
</p> 
<img src='bar.png' style='position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;' />
```

If you want the rest of the page to continue without using position:absolute, you could add a margin to the next html object. Otherwise it will overlap the absolute objects.

Answer (score 0):

Without an example, it's difficult to say what the exact problem is.

My best guess would be that your navigation bar contains floated list items, that don't have a clearfix applied. This would give it a zero height, meaning a subsequent paragraph would overlap slightly.

Try creating a clearfix CSS class and adding it to your nav bar.

Something along the lines of:

```
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
.clearfix {
    display: block;
}
```

Applied like:

```
<nav class="clearfix"></nav>
<p>Extra text</p>
```