# Changing hover function to toggle function breaks links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I have a dropdown menu that currently displays the dropdown unordered list on hover, which are lists of links. Hover is problematic for users and I want to change the to 'click' or 'toggle'. Here is the code currently in the site:

```
 $("#main_nav .dropdown").hover(function() { 
             $('.dropdown-menu', this).fadeIn("fast"); 
             $('.nav_main .mega-menu-column ul').attr("style", "display:flex; display: -ms-flexbox;");
             $(this).addClass('active');
        },
        function() 
            { $('.dropdown-menu', this).fadeOut("fast"); $(this).removeClass('active');
            });
```

if I switch the .hover to .toggle the drop down menus work as I would expect them to. The problem is it now breaks my links. When I click on them they do nothing and go nowhere. Here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="nav_main">
        <li class="active"><a href="/#top">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Decisions <b class="caret"></b></a>                      
            <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-menu" id="decisions">
                <li class="mega-menu-column">
                    <ul>
                        <span>
                            <li><a href="https://www.canlii.org/en/sk/skca/">Our Decision on CanLII</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://scc-csc.lexum.com/scc-csc/en/nav.do">SCC Decisions</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://scc-csc.lexum.com/scc-csc/scr/en/nav_date.do">Canada Supreme Court Reports (PDF)</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://app.vlex.com">vLex Canada Open</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://library.lawsociety.sk.ca/databasespub/digest2008.htm">Sask Cases Judicially Considered</a></li>
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <li><a href="https://decisions.fct-cf.gc.ca/fc-cf/en/nav.do">Federal Court</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://soquij.qc.ca/fr/services-aux-citoyens/english-translation">Quebec (translated decisions)</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://decision.tcc-cci.gc.ca/tcc-cci/en/nav.do">Tax Court of Canada</a></li>
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <li class="list-heading">Tribunals</li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.canlii.org/en/sk/skaia/">Automobile Injury Appeal Commission</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.canlii.org/en/sk/sklss/">Law Society of Saskatchewan</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.canlii.org/en/sk/skla/">Labour Arbitration Awards – Sask</a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.canlii.org/en/sk/sklrb/">Sask LRB (CanLII)</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.sasklabourrelationsboard.com/Decisions-Reasons">Sask LRB</a></li>
                        </span>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Is there any easily explainable reason as to my this simple switch in code is causing the links to stop working completely?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: also, if I right click on any link and "open in new tab" the link opens just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to precisely reproduce the issue with the code you provided, but I did observe issues clicking some of the links.

Removing the invalid `span` elements from the `ul` seems to have corrected the observed issue.

Try removing those `span` tags from the `ul`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

[Allowed child elements of ul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242041/allowed-child-elements-of-ul)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your .toggle is hijacking the `click` event for the whole container.  So when you click a link it's toggling the menu rather than firing the default click for a link.  You may try stopping propagation on the links, so it doesn't fire the click event on the parent menu: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: Where, in the code, exactly would you attempt to stop the event at?

Comment: On the `a` tag. Something like:  $('.mega-menu-column a').on('click', function(event) { event.stopPropagation() }