# Position caret on dropdown menu Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How can I position a caret out of the drop-down menu? This is what I'm getting until now.

[image]

This is what I'm trying to get. I'm trying to position the arrow like this dropdown menu on Github.

[image]

This is the code of my dropdown menu:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md pl-4 user-dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown btn-group">
        <a class="navbar-brand dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="bd-versions" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu text-center mt-2">
          <span><i class="caret-up fas fa-caret-up ml-2"></i></span>
          <li>
            <a href="{{ route('login') }}">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning text-dark">Sign-in now</button>
            </a>
          </li>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <li>
            <h6>Don't have an account?</h6>
            <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Sign-up here</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md">
      <span><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md">
      <span><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you want to ask?

Comment: Edited my question. I just want to position the arrow out of the drop-down menu. Just like you can see in the example picture.

Comment: You cant just use several tags as direct descendants of a `ul`. Only `li` and other lists (`ul` or `ol`) may be direct descendants of a `ul`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242041/allowed-child-elements-of-ul.

Comment: I thought that it was going to work like that. But what can I do for position it like in the example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.container {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
}

.user-dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%) !important;
  top: 100% !important;
}

.arrow-up {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md pl-4 user-dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a class="navbar-brand dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="bd-versions" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            B<i class="fas fa-user"></i>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu text-center mt-2">
            <div class="arrow-up"></div>
            <a href="{{ route('login') }}">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning text-dark">Sign-in now</button>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <h6>Don't have an account?</h6>
            <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Sign-up here</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md">
        <span><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md">
        <span><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work correctly. In the code, you're positioning it beside the user's button. And what I'm trying to get is making that the caret appears in the outline of the dropdown menu.

Comment: how exactly do you want it to work? can you please tell?

Comment: where exactly do you want the arrow icon?

Comment: I edited the first image of my question. I want it on the top of the dropdown menu. Aligned with the user's button.

Comment: For nesome reason i am unable to incorporate font awesome icons in the code, but it in case the icons are not aligned, just change the left value of dropdown to the number of pixels of your user font awesome icon.

Comment: I checked it once again. It doesn't work as I want. The problem is not really aligning the icon. The real problem is positioning it in the outline of the <ul>.

Comment: Hmmm,,, ok. let me know if i could help further. i will b happy to help

Comment: I want to know, how can I position it? Please, look at my question and the example that I'm trying to get.

Comment: Updated the answer. is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for. I'm going to update it

Comment: @danhergir was it helpful ?